# Custom CM theme crashes

Tags: cyanogenmod, themes

I used ThemeDIY to create a CM12 theme which worked, but I set one of the colors to semi-transparent. I exported and installed it, and now many of the apps crash. The crash report says:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[app goes here]}: java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque"

Now, both ThemeDIY and the CM12 theme chooser crash when I try to launch them, so I have no way of either editing the faulty theme or switching to the stock system theme.

---

Possibly helpful information:
Nexus 4, CM12.1, ThemeDIY v1.0

Comment: Simply uninstall your custom theme and reboot your device. This will reset the theme to the default, stock one.

Comment: Whenever I try to uninstall the theme, the Package installer crashes.

Comment: Do you have *debug mode* enabled? Try if you can connect to your shell using `adb shell` and uninstall your theme with `pm uninstall <package name>`. You need to find the package name, though.

Comment: It returns an error message: Failure [DELETE FAILED INTERNAL ERROR]

Comment: Try `adb uninstall <package name>`. If it fails, you need to *uninstall manually* ie. delete the apk and all folders; this requires root, though.

Comment: The theme uninstalled fine, and everything works now. Thanks!